# Postgres function to merge two json objects with overlapping keys into one object

Tags: postgresql, json

I've got the following JSON object:

```
{
    "a" : {
        "0" : 2,
        "1" : 4,
        "3" : 6,
    },
    "b" : {
        "2" : 8,
        "1" : 10, /*note this key exists in "a" too*/
        "4" : 12,
    }
}
```

I'd like to generate the following object and then be able to extract an element from it like so:

```
{
        "0" : 2,
        "1" : 10,
        "2" : 8,
        "3" : 6,
        "4" : 12,
}
```

Extraction: `object->>'1'` should return `'10'`

Basically, I have two arrays with potentially overlapping keys and I want to merge the two, giving one array precedence.

How can I accomplish this? Ideally I'd call a function like `arrayMerge(a, b)` and it gave `'a'` higher precedence than `'b'`

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: Have a look at [Merging Concatenating JSON(B) columns in query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30101603/merging-concatenating-jsonb-columns-in-query) over at StackOverflow

Answer (score 20):

If you're using PostgreSQL 9.5 (at least), you can use the [concatenation operator (`||`) on `jsonb` types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) (and you can convert `json` to `jsonb` if necessary first).

For example:

```
WITH test(data) AS (
    VALUES ('{
        "a" : {
            "0" : 2,
            "1" : 4,
            "3" : 6
        },
        "b" : {
            "2" : 8,
            "1" : 10,
            "4" : 12
        }
    }'::jsonb)
)
SELECT (data->'a') || (data->'b') FROM test
```

will produce:

```
{"0": 2, "1": 10, "2": 8, "3": 6, "4": 12}
```

(Please note that, in this particular example, the parentheses around `(data->'a')` matter.)

You can modify the example above to get a specific value, as you requested, for example:

```
SELECT (((data->'a') || (data->'b'))->'1')::text::integer FROM test
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment about the the parentheses around (data->'a') which really matter! It saved me a few minutes more of head scratching